# Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'ProgressEvent<EventTarget>' Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model-viewer

I have a project in Angular and integrate the 3d model viewer from modelviewer.dev
I´m tying to capture a custom event developed from them, and this is the code:

```
modelViewerload.addEventListener('progress', (ev) => {
        const totalProgress1 = ev.detail;
        console.log(totalProgress1);
        progress.classList.toggle('show', totalProgress1! < 1);
        bar.style.transform = `scaleX(${totalProgress1})`;
    } );
```

The error says that property detail dont exist in the event, but when I print in console the event, this is result:

CustomEvent {isTrusted: false, detail: {…}, type: 'progress', target: model-viewer#test, currentTarget: model-viewer#test, …}
isTrusted
:
false
bubbles
:
false
cancelBubble
:
false
cancelable
:
false
composed
:
false
currentTarget
:
null
defaultPrevented
:
false
detail
:
{totalProgress: 1}
eventPhase
:
0
path
:
(9) [model-viewer#test, div.d3, div.contenedor, app-colorvisualizer, app-root, body, html, document, Window]
returnValue
:
true
srcElement
:
model-viewer#test
target
:
model-viewer#test
timeStamp
:
6277.899999856949
type
:
"progress"
[[Prototype]]
:
CustomEvent

Clearly exist the property detail, but typescript don´t admit it and this is the error Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'ProgressEvent'.
I wonder if this have a solution or not.

I tried to put this: ev.detail? and also tried ev.detail! and this not resolve the problem.

Comment: I would just cast: `(ev as any).detail`.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your issue using the built-in **CustomEvent** type

```
modelViewerload.addEventListener('progress', (ev:CustomEvent) => {
        const totalProgress1 = ev.detail;
        console.log(totalProgress1);
        progress.classList.toggle('show', totalProgress1! < 1);
        bar.style.transform = `scaleX(${totalProgress1})`;
    } );
```

You could also extend it

```
interface MyCustomEvent extends CustomEvent {
  detail:number
}
```